# Indexing with joins

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm new to the concept of indexes but I'm trying to figure out how its working.

I have the following query that I want to improve the performance of.

```
explain analyze select to_char(rental_date, 'month') as month, count(*) count
from rental
join instrument on rental.instrument_id = instrument.instrument_id
where extract(year from rental_date) = 2020
group by month, extract(month from rental_date)
order by extract(month from rental_date) asc
;
```

Execution plan

```
       QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=75.10..75.55 rows=15 width=48) (actual time=14.204..14.821 rows=12 loops=1)
   Group Key: (date_part('month'::text, (rental.rental_date)::timestamp without time zone)), (to_char((rental.rental_date)::timestamp with time zone, 'month'::text))
   ->  Sort  (cost=75.10..75.14 rows=15 width=40) (actual time=14.121..14.298 rows=1540 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('month'::text, (rental.rental_date)::timestamp without time zone)), (to_char((rental.rental_date)::timestamp with time zone, 'month'::text))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 169kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.20..74.81 rows=15 width=40) (actual time=7.912..13.166 rows=1540 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (rental.instrument_id = instrument.instrument_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on rental  (cost=0.00..73.39 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.061..2.027 rows=1540 loops=1)
                     Filter: (date_part('year'::text, (rental_date)::timestamp without time zone) = '2020'::double precision)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1511
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.09..1.09 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=9 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on instrument  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.016 rows=9 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 3.908 ms
 Execution Time: 15.072 ms
(15 rows)
```

My idea was to have indexes on instrument_id and on rental_date because intrument_id is a foreign key and rental_date is in the where clause.

```
create index isx_rental ON rental(instrument_id);
create index isx_date ON rental(rental_date);
```

But this doesn't affect the runtime at all.

Why doesn't this help me with the performance?

Comment: 15 **milli**seconds seems pretty quick. How fast do you need that to be?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `extract(year from rental_date) = 2020` can't use an index on `rental_date` as the index doesn't store the result of the expression, only the original column value.

You need to at least change that condition to:

```
where rental_date >= date '2020-01-01'
  and rental_date < date '2021-01-01'
```

in order for the index to be considered at all. Whether that improves the performance is hard to say without seeing the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with `extract(year from rental_date) = 2020` cannot use an index, because the function need to be applied for each row before the comparison can be done. You should whenever possible not extract a portion of a date but use a range instead. In this case you could use `rental_date >= '2020-01-01' AND rental_date < '2021-01-01'`.

Then it's a little weird that you group by the alias `month`, which is the month (as name) and then again by `extract(month from rental_date)` which is also the month (yet numerical). Those can be bijectively mapped. I don't know if the optimizer gets that, so you better only group by one of them. It might also help, if you grouped by the same expression you order by. So `GROUP BY extract(month from rental_date)` seems more promising.

In short, you can try to rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT to_char(rental_date, 'month') month,
       count(*) count
       FROM rental
            INNER JOIN instrument
                       ON rental.instrument_id = instrument.instrument_id
       WHERE rental_date >= '2020-01-01'
             AND rental_date < '2021-01-01'
       GROUP BY extract(month from rental_date)
       ORDER BY extract(month from rental_date) ASC;
```

For `instrument`, there's only one column involved, `instrument_id`, and that might be a primary key, i.e. it is already indexed. If not, index it, it might help the `JOIN`.

The next thing is, that only one index can be used on a table in a `SELECT` (unless it appears more often in the `FROM` clause, but that's not the case here). So your two indexes on `rental` are one too many. You need a composite index.

Now for `rental` you could try an index on `(rental_date, instrument_id)` to support the `WHERE` and the `JOIN`. To also support the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` you can try to add `extract(month from rental_date)` to the index as well, making it an index on `(rental_date, instrument_id, extract(month from rental_date))`.